# load content into already open jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

Upon clicking a link in an open dialog the content gets loaded into the parent window from which I opened the dialog.
How can I force the content to be loaded into the dialog instead of the parent?

Parent:

```
dialogDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
dialogDiv.dialog(myProps);
dialogDiv.html(myData);
dialogDiv.dialog('open');
```

Dialog popup:

```
<a href="mysite.com">click</a>
```

Comment: What kind of content are we talking about here (i.e., HTML/JSON)? If HTML, is your intent for it to act like an IFRAME?

Comment: It is plain HTML. I need to show a table so I would like to have paging enabled. I stream the data via ajax. This all works except when I click the paging-link the parent loads all the data.

Comment: Nevertheless it should not matter where the content comes from or what data-type is used, simply loading the data on the spot instead of the parent should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on the dialog `<div>` and [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the anchor (to prevent the normal go-to-href behavior), like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
  dialogDiv.load(this.href);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Just change the `$("a")` to be a bit more specific...only selecting whatever links you want to load in the dialog.  Also those pages should only be fragments, or use a different selector, for example if you want the `<div id="content">` from the page in the `href`, it'd look like this:

```
dialogDiv.load(this.href + " #content");
```